# Compare every row value elements in pandas Df and input a string based on comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, warnings

I am new in handling pandas Df.
I want to compare every column elements of each row.

Requirement:
If all elements in the columns of 1 row is zero then input 'More False' in new column filled with zeros corresponding to its index.

See below Df for clear understanding

```
My Data Frame:

       Time     Brake      Speed         Strgangle   index   Target
0     1678.39  0.000000   0.000000        0.000000  167739      0
1     1678.40  15.00000   0.000000        0.000000  167740      0
2     1678.41  0.000000   8.000000        0.000000  167741      0
3     1678.42  0.000000   0.000000        2.000000  167742      0
4     1678.43  5.000000   20.10000        0.000000  167743      0
5     1678.44  0.150000   0.000000        -1.16500  167744      0
6     1678.45  0.000000   20.10           2.000000  167742      0
7     1678.47  0.150000   25.00000        -1.16500  167744      0


My Requirement :

1. If Brake = 0, Speed =0, Strg angle=0 
--> Input a str in corresponding Target index as 'More False'
2. If Brake = Value, Speed = Value, Strg angle=Value 
--> Input a str in corresponding Target index as 'More True'
3. As above conditions i should input the string in Target column based on my requirement
```

.

Actual Df required :

```
       Time     Brake      Speed         Strgangle   index   Target
0     1678.39  0.000000   0.000000        0.000000  167739      MoreFalse
1     1678.40  15.00000   0.000000        0.000000  167740      False
2     1678.41  0.000000   8.000000        0.000000  167741      False
3     1678.42  0.000000   0.000000        2.000000  167742      False
4     1678.43  5.000000   20.10000        0.000000  167743      True
5     1678.44  0.150000   0.000000        -1.16500  167744      True
6     1678.45  0.000000   20.10           2.000000  167742      True
7     1678.47  0.150000   25.00000        -1.16500  167744      MoreTrue
```

I have tried using an If loop to input my required string in Target column, but i am receiving SettingWithcopy warning.

I am sure that there will be some easy approach for the above problem.

Comment: look at np.select

Comment: My Requirement/Conditions :(@FilipeAleixo)

1. If Brake = 0, Speed =0, Strg angle=0 
--> Input a str in corresponding Target index as 'More False'
2. If Brake = Value, Speed = Value, Strg angle=Value 
--> Input a str in corresponding Target index as 'More True'
3. As above conditions i should input the string in Target column based on my requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only have 4 possibilities, find the number of non-zero values across the columns, then map the result:

```
d = {0: 'MoreFalse', 1: 'False', 2: 'True', 3: 'MoreTrue'}
df['Target'] = df[['Brake', 'Speed', 'Strgangle']].ne(0).sum(1).map(d)
```

#### Output:

```
      Time  Brake  Speed  Strgangle   index     Target
0  1678.39   0.00    0.0      0.000  167739  MoreFalse
1  1678.40  15.00    0.0      0.000  167740      False
2  1678.41   0.00    8.0      0.000  167741      False
3  1678.42   0.00    0.0      2.000  167742      False
4  1678.43   5.00   20.1      0.000  167743       True
5  1678.44   0.15    0.0     -1.165  167744       True
6  1678.45   0.00   20.1      2.000  167742       True
7  1678.47   0.15   25.0     -1.165  167744   MoreTrue
```

Comment: Thank you so much...It works...
(But still I am getting SettingWithcopyWarning. Is there any other method to avoid such warnings !!!)

Comment: @esakkiponraj.e Please see [Question 4 at the bottom of coldspeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/4333359). The code above is not problematic,. The issue is that further up in your code you must have created a view from a slicing operation, so it will keep giving you this warning. You will need to add `.copy()` after your slicing or instead use `.loc` to slice.

Comment: Thank you @ALollz
Also, could you kindly explain the usage of .ne function here....
I am surfing about the .ne function, but i cant get the clear idea of its usage !!
Thank you...

Comment: @esakkiponraj.e it's just a convenience wrapper for writing `DataFrame != 0` (which will perform the element wise comparison of each value with 0). This allows you to chain operations with fewer closing parenthesis and characters. `ne(0)` is read as "not equal to zero". There is also `.eq()` for equal to and `.lt()`, `.le()`, `.gt()`, `.ge()` for less than, less than or equal to, greater than and greater than or equal to.